# How to lock the permission of a folder?

Tags: windows-7

I have created a folder with access denied permission. How to lock that permission so others cannot change that? I would like to protect my folder from others.

Comment: what is your OS.

Comment: microsoft windows 7

Comment: If you have already done access denied permission, and if other users will try to change it, he will be asked for a username and password. but if other user is administrator he can modify the permission. You can also try Folder Lock.

Comment: Are the other users admin also?  Are these files on your local macine or a fileserver?  you need to provide more details about where the files are stored and the Windows privileges you and the other users have.  Oh, and if you are really paranoid skip the permissions, use encryption.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using the deny persmission on your folder.  If you do this and a user who is denied access tries to change permissions, they will get rejected - possibly requesting a username/password depending on your setup.

If you want the users the right to use the files, but not modify permissions, you can used advanced file permissions by right clicking > properties > security > edit > advanced